# Name of a book featuring a "Book of Rules"

Tags: story-identification

I'm trying to find the name of an SF&F book I read a long time ago. One of the ideas in the book was that, as the world had been created by angels, it required a '*Book of Rules*' to make the world work. One of the rules was '*All beautiful women shall dress scantily*' (or similar); another was '*barbarians shall dress in loincloths*' (or similar). One of the lead characters was a barbarian who had previously been a trucker here on Earth who dies (or was dying) in a crash.

Comment: Great series by Jack Chalker; and it's "All beautiful women must be scantily clad - weather permitting".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The book you're looking for is most likely [The River of Dancing Gods](http://www.librarything.com/work/65718) by [Jack L. Chalker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack_L._Chalker), the first in a series of [seven books](http://www.librarything.com/series/Dancing+Gods).

Comment: One warning; the author died before completing this series.. Although it has lots of humor and spoofiness, the characters can be rather engaging.  The author then set up a collosal clif-hanger, with massive un-resolved 'Oh my god!' level issues... Then died before finishing.  I'd read them anyway, but be aware, the final 'payoff' is not going to be forthcoming, at least not from Jack Chalker.