# Series of books about a wizard who travels to the future

Tags: story-identification, books

I'm looking for the title of a particular book in a series.

What I remember is that it was a series of books.  The first book in the series had a powerful wizard who travels to the future and finds two of the main characters.  1. Joe, a truck driver 2. Marge(?) a waitress fleeing an abusive relationship.

The two main characters are taken to another world ruled by magic.  Joe becomes a Conan type hero while Marge(?) transforms into a Pixie/Fairy?

Been years since I read the book and the series. Does anyone know what it is?

Comment: probable duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4255/name-of-a-book-featuring-a-book-of-rules

Comment: @otis - Yep; that's clearly the Dancing Gods series.   The only detail that the OP got wrong was it wasn't traveling to the future, but to another, related, world.

Answer (score 9):

[*The River of Dancing Gods*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1416797.The_River_of_Dancing_Gods) by Jack L. Chalker

> Life had not been kind to Joe and Marge. Now, according to the stranger who met them on a road that wasn't there, they were due to die in nineteen minutes, eighteen seconds. But the ferryboat that waited to take them across the Sea of Dreams could bring them to a new and perhaps better life.
>
> There lay a world where fairies still danced by moonlight and sorcery became real. Joe could become a mighty-thewed barbarian warrior. Marge could be beautiful and find her magical self.
>
> This was a world where Hell still strove to win its ancient war and demon princes sent men into battles of dark magic. It was a world where Joe and Marge must somehow help prevent the coming of Armageddon.
>
> And it was even as Throckmorton P. Ruddygore, the strange wizard, had promised. But there was a great deal more, as they soon learned.

It's the first of a five-book series featuring the characters - each book matches the pattern "______ of the Dancing Gods".